# Implement base method, yet still provide own implementation?

Tags: c#, .net, parsing, abstract-class, dry

There are 2 strings to parse:

```
param1=value1;param2=value2;param3=value3;
```

and...

```
param1=value1;param4=value4;param999=value999;
```

Every parameter has to be parsed different because they contain complex information of different types. In all glory of the holy DRY paradigm, it seems appropriate that parsing of '`param1`' is only done once. A base class implementation may look like this:

```
public abstract class MyBase {

    public ComplexObj MyParam1 { get; set; }

    public abstract static MyBase Parse(string myString) {
        // some sinful witchcraft that parses the value
        // of param1 into the ComplexObj MyParam1
        // and returns an instance of MyBase
    }

}
```

and a derived class may look like the following:

```
public class MyDerived : MyBase {

    public ComplexObj2 MyParam2 { get; set; }
    public ComplexObj3 MyParam3 { get; set; }

    public static MyDerived Parse(string myString) {
        params = myString.Split('params/values')
        base.Parse(params[0]);
        MyParam2 = magicParseParam2[1];
        MyParam3 = magicParseParam3[2];
    }
}
```

Now, this obviously doesn't work because I declared the `Parse()` method of the base class as abstract, forcing every derived class to provide its own implementation of the method. But in this particular case, I don't want to write the parsing of `param1` for every implementation.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: There is no such thing as an abstract static method with implementation. (1) abstract methods have no implementation (2) static methods can't be abstract or virtual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the base method virtual rather than abstract. Then you can call base.Parse(string) in the implementing class.

Edit: Oh and don't make them static. It looks like for what you want to be doing you want to be creating an instance of the class.

Example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hfw7t1ce.aspx